# Expose single sentence through paragraph-like formatting

Tags: typography, highlighting, emphasis

I was wondering if there exists a "common-practice"-possibility to expose a single sentence to
make it stand out without adding too much weight to the overall look of a page (i.e. I don't want it to just be bold).

I was thinking about something like a combination of:

- starting a new line
- slightly increased distance to previous and following line
- italics

as I figured for my purpose just using emphasis didn't really do the trick.
If there is no standard way to do something like that I would appreciate help with defining my own command to do so.

Comment: The standard practice uses `\emph{sentence}`, but if it is a bit long, you have the `quote` or `quotation` environment, or the customisable `quoting` environment from the homonymous package.

Comment: If bolt or italic (or \texttt) is too much, try finding a slightly different non-LaTeX font (fontspec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Bernard's comment into further investigations I came up with this, which solves the problem.

Define an environment similar to quote:

```
\newenvironment{block}%
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=0.0in\rightmargin=0.0in}  \item[]  }%
  {\endlist}
```

Combine the command with emphasis (or italics or...):

```
\begin{block}
    \emph{Some text...}
\end{block}
```